# Custody Verification in Tezos

Tags: node

Can we do custody verification in Tezos like we do for other currencies  for example for bitcoin related coins and ethereum the custody verification can be done using address , message and signed message.

Can we achieve something similar in Tezos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can sign arbitrary bytes of information in Tezos to prove that Alice owns address X

See here: [How can I sign a message with my Ledger?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/61/how-can-i-sign-a-message-with-my-ledger)

Comment: the process that you mentioned like signing a message with ledger will incur a cost as well which i dont wanna do . Can you if the approach i asked is feasible

Comment: There is no cost to simply signing bytes using a ledger. Signing is not a online/on-chain operation; it is completely offline and therefore impossible to incur a cost.